# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh^2(z)}\frac{\ln(z)}{z} \, dz = \frac{4G}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2e}\right)-\frac{4\beta'(2)}{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I recently evaluated this integral, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh^2(z)}\frac{\ln(z)}{z} \, dz = \frac{4G}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2e}\right)-\frac{4\beta'(2)}{\pi}$ ,
and I was wondering if there was a closed form for $\beta'(2)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\ln(2n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}$ to simplify my expression.

Here my approach to compute the integral,

Consider , $\forall a \in \mathbb{R},\,\,\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(at)}{\cosh(t)} \, dt = \frac{\pi/2}{\cosh(a\,\pi/2)}$
$\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\sin(at)}{\cosh(t)} \, dt = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{\sinh(a \pi/2)}{\cosh^2(a\,\pi/2)}$

so $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh^2(z)}\frac{\ln(z)}{z} \, dz=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(zt \, \frac{2}{\pi})\ln(z)}{z} \frac{t}{\cosh(t)} \,dt\, dz$  , with $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(zt \, \frac{2}{\pi})\ln(z)}{z}  dz = -\gamma \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\frac{2}{\pi}t)$.

We got, $I=\frac{2}{\pi}(\ln(\frac{\pi}{2})-\gamma )\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{\cosh(t)}  dt -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\ln(t)}{\cosh(t)}  dt $.

Note that, $\left(\beta(s)\Gamma(s)\right)'_{s\rightarrow 2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\ln(t)}{\cosh(t)}dt\,\,\,\, \Leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,2\beta'(2)+2(1-\gamma )G=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\ln(t)}{\cosh(t)}dt$.

So in conclusion , $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh^2(z)}\frac{\ln(z)}{z} \, dz = \frac{4G}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2e}\right)-\frac{4\beta'(2)}{\pi}$

Comment: This would also be a fun contour integration exercise

Comment: Probably useless, but your integral reduces to $\int_0^\infty( \frac{1}{\cosh x} -1)\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}dx$